# Jquery on click function not working on wordpress but working on local host xamp html design

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

if i run my custom design in html or php using xampp server this function works well but if i add it on wordpress theme this doesn't work and show's no error in console did i missed something here i'm not a common wordpress user just for this project please help.

main.js

```
$('#menu').on('click', function(){

        $('.side-nav').fadeToggle('800','linear');
        $('body').css('height', wh());
        $('html,body').addClass('overflow-hidden');

        $(window).one('resize orientationchange', function(){ 
            wh();
        });
    });

    $('#close-nav').on('click', function(){
        console.log('test');
        $('.side-nav').fadeToggle('fast','linear');
        $('body').removeAttr('style');
        $('html,body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
    });
```

functions.php

```
function css_script_enqueue()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script('main1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('main-min1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main-min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'css_script_enqueue');
```

sidebar.php

```
<div class="side-nav">
        <div class="close-wrap">
            <i id="close-nav" class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-a">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav-b">
            <li><a href="donateNOW.php">Donate now</a></li>
            <li><a href="joinNOW.php">Join us now</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

header.php

```
<title>The house of Joy - Orphanage</title>
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: What's the error shown in the console?

Comment: there no error in the console which is why it's hard to look on what is wrong cause if i test the same codes in xampp htdocs change all the tag to php it works well the link in side bar toggles. but if i change the tag into wordpress tag and place the project in wordpress theme activate it the link sidebar is not working it doesn't toggle.

Comment: how do you import that scripts to your theme?

Comment: i use this one:

function css_script_enqueue()
{
 wp_enqueue_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
 wp_enqueue_script('main1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
 wp_enqueue_script('main-min1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main-min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'css_script_enqueue');

Comment: @BugFixerDev-Migz looks ok on me, have you tried to put that inside of this function `jQuery(function ($) {});`

Comment: still doesn't work sir help T_T i've left php for already 5yrs ago i'm more on a .net C# is there something i missed to config in wordpress?

Comment: i added some of the script maybe you can understand what seem to be it's problem?

Comment: I think the problem is that the call of the function is already done without the whole dom finish to load up and ready. i already have fixed the problem here sir. i added a document. ready function